# What is the Sorting property in WPF Tookit's DataGridControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

I am trying to add a custom column sorting logic on WPF Toolkit. In `System.Windows.Control.DataGrid`, this can be done by specifying its `Sorting` property

```
<DataGrid Name="DG1"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Sorting="DataGrid_ThreeWaySorting">
```

and its code behind

```
    private void DataGrid_ThreeWaySorting(object sender, DataGridSortingEventArgs e)
    {
        //custom logic here
    }
```

How to achieve this on WPF Toolkit's `DataGridControl` ? It does not have `Sorting` property.

It is slower to sort the bound items, so I am looking to have the sort on the UI level.

Answer (score 0):

Can you perform sorting using a CollectionViewSource?

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="Items" Source="{Binding}" >
   <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Description" />
       <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Id" />
   </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

Bind to the resource:

```
<DataGridControl Name="DG1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Items}}">
```

Comment: How to have 3-way-sorting with CollectionViewSource ? (Ascending, Descending, No Sort)

Comment: Add a sort description for each property that you want to sort on and specify the sort direction